# How to add API key in retrofit when passing Geocoding

Tags: android, geocoding

I still new to Google API and I found that my apps facing issues such as You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Map Platforms APIs. I think I need to add API key in retrofit client to get the key but I dont have the idea how to do it.

I debugged my apps already, it can get the current location like ( lat, lng) but cannot pass through JsonObject and saying it need API Key. 
I tested in chrome, the address that i get in URL need add a key and it can get the location such as this: 
[Link](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1,%20Jalan%20Tun%20Fuad%20Stephens,%20Pusat%20Bandar%20Kota%20Kinabalu,%2088000%20Kota%20Kinabalu,%20Sabah,%20Malaysi&key=AIzaSyBW3rhW1EhjhW36DmMyoTTBup4E6Gu1LCY)

```
public interface IGeoCoordinates {
@GET("maps/api/geocode/json")
Call<String> getGeoCode(@Query("address") String address);

@GET("maps/api/directions/json")
Call<String> getDirections(@Query("origin") String origin, @Query("destination") String destination);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
@GET("/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=true&language=EN")
Observable<TheResponse> getGeocoding(
        @Query("latlng") String latLng,
        @Query("key") String key);
```

Basically you just need to add `@Query("key") String key` and provide it.

Comment: is that neccessary to incude the Observable<TheResponse> and the String latlng?

Comment: Nope.I just copied the snippet from my code - if you don't use Rx you don't have to use Observable or Single etc, just use whatever you got. Regarding actual list of parameters - it is here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro . If I remember correctly, either address or latlng must be there.